Patroni error while checking status of patroni
I am getting below status for patroni on DB1 and DB2 node. Please suggest how to fix.
This is how I attach the patroni.yml , etcd services and etcd.yml
Environment:
Two DB servers (Postgres15. RHEL 9)
1 ETCD server
[root@db2 db2]# etcdctl version
etcdctl version: 3.5.15
API version: 3.5

patroni.service - Patroni Orchestration
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/patroni.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
Active: active (running) since Mon 2024-10-07 12:56:19 IST; 8min ago
Main PID: 6054 (patroni)
Tasks: 2 (limit: 34980)
Memory: 27.1M
CPU: 606ms
CGroup: /system.slice/patroni.service
└─6054 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/patroni /etc/patroni.yml

Oct 07 13:04:56 db2 patroni[6054]: 2024-10-07 13:04:56,213 ERROR: Failed to get list of machines from http://192.168.0.113:2379/v2: MaxRe>
Oct 07 13:04:56 db2 patroni[6054]: 2024-10-07 13:04:56,214 INFO: waiting on etcd
Oct 07 13:05:01 db2 patroni[6054]: 2024-10-07 13:05:01,221 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=0, status=>
Oct 07 13:05:01 db2 patroni[6054]: 2024-10-07 13:05:01,223 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=0, status=>
Oct 07 13:05:01 db2 patroni[6054]: 2024-10-07 13:05:01,225 ERROR: Failed to get list of machines from http://192.168.0.113:2379/v2: MaxRe>
Oct 07 13:05:01 db2 patroni[6054]: 2024-10-07 13:05:01,225 INFO: waiting on etcd
Oct 07 13:05:06 db2 patroni[6054]: 2024-10-07 13:05:06,232 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=0, status=>
Oct 07 13:05:06 db2 patroni[6054]: 2024-10-07 13:05:06,233 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=0, status=>
Oct 07 13:05:06 db2 patroni[6054]: 2024-10-07 13:05:06,234 ERROR: Failed to get list of machines from http://192.168.0.113:2379/v2: MaxRe>
Oct 07 13:05:06 db2 patroni[6054]: 2024-10-07 13:05:06,235 INFO: waiting on etcd
lines 1-20/20 (END)

    scope: postgres
namespace: /db/
name: node2
restapi:
  listen: 192.168.0.112:8008
  connect_address: 192.168.0.112:8008
etcd:
  host: 192.168.0.113:2379
bootstrap:
  dcs:
    ttl: 30
    loop_wait: 10
    retry_timeout: 10
    maximum_lag_on_failover: 1048576
    postgresql:
    use_pg_rewind: true
  initdb:
    - encoding: UTF8
    - data-checksums
  pg_hba:
    - host replication replicator   127.0.0.1/32 md5
    - host replication replicator   192.168.0.109/0   md5
    - host replication replicator   192.168.0.112/0   md5
    - host all all   0.0.0.0/0   md5
  users:
    admin:
       password: admin
       options:
       - createrole
       - createdb
postgresql:
   listen: 192.168.0.112:5432
   connect_address: 192.168.0.112:5432
   data_dir:     /var/lib/pgsql/15/data
   pgpass:     /tmp/pgpass
    replication:
      username:   replicator
      password:   "replicator"
    superuser:
      username:   postgres
      password:   "postgres"
      parameters:
      unix_socket_directories:  '.'
 replication:
      username:   replicator
      password:   "replicator"
    superuser:
      username:   postgres
      password:   "postgres"
      parameters:
      unix_socket_directories:  '.'
tags:
   nofailover:   false
   noloadbalance:   false
   clonefrom:   false
   nosync:   fals

